# Installation Error with WordPress 4.6.1 and CiviCRM 4.7

Tags: wordpress, installation

After successfully trialing CiviCRM on a local desktop PC, we have decided to install on our hosted wordpress website.  I am following the instructions as listed here to the letter (3rd attempt) - https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Installing+CiviCRM+for+WordPress

1. Login to your WordPress site with Administrator level permissions.
2. Go to plugins page:http:///wp-admin/plugins.php.
3. Click the'Activate' link to activate the CiviCRM plugin.

When I try to go to Settings > CiviCRM Installer: http:///wp-admin/options-general.php?page=civicrm-install

All I get is this error - "Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page." 
And when I go to settings in the wordpress admin panel there is no CiviCRM options appearing.

So I am unable to proceed.

I have checked permissions and made all relevant folders writable (i think?). So not sure what the problem is?  Any suggestions please?

Comment: If civicrm does not appear in your wordpress admin plugins list then I would suggest that civicrm is perhaps not installed correctly or in the correct directory.  After unpacking the civicrm zip file, my civicrm files are in root/.../wp-content/plugins/civicrm and in the latter directory, the installed directories and files are as below:

Comment: Revised
If civicrm does not appear in your wordpress admin plugins list then I would suggest that civicrm is perhaps not installed correctly or is in the wrong directory.  After unpacking the civicrm zip file, my civicrm files are in root/.../wp-content/plugins/civicrm and in the latter directory, the installed directories and files are as below:
Directories: [assets][civicrm][includes],languages][wp-cli]
Files: [readme.md][civicrm.php][civicrm.settings.php][readme.txt][uninstall.php]
Can you confirm that all those items are present?
Note; there is a civicrm directory within civicrm

Comment: I completely removed and then reinstalled and checked all the paths were correct.

Comment: I completely removed and then reinstalled civicrm and checked all the paths were correct. The problem I now have is that by default, civicrm is picking up MySQL settings that are defined in wp-config.php, and if I try to change these (DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) it wipes out the entire website.  Luckily I backed up the config file!
So I can proceed, I just cannot specify which DB I want CiviCRM to use, as I don't seem to be able to change from the one defined in wp-config.php.